# Trying to "like" a particular page

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have authenticated my app, and I'm able to post to the user's feed stream.  But I have a button in my app which I want to allow the user to "like" my app's page on Facebook.  So I'm trying to do:

```
client.PostAsync("/1211212121212121/likes", null);
```

This fails, and I get the following detail in the exception:

> "(OAuthException) (#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call."

When the user is first authenticating to Facebook, I have the following extended attributes:

- read_stream
- publish_stream
- publish_checkins
- user_likes
- friends_likes

I honestly don't really know what "friends_likes" is.  The Facebook documentation isn't really clear on the differences between "user_likes" and "friends_likes", so I just added them both.  However, it did no good as I still can't seem to "like" the page I want.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

user_likes = What does the user like?

friends_likes = What do the friends of the user like?

Are you developing an desktop app? Otherwise i would just include the Facebook like button.

Comment: It's a mobile app.  It's already authenticating to Facebook, and I want to have a button where the user can "like" our page on Facebook automatically.  I could open it in an in-app browser control, but they'd have to re-authenticate again I think.

Answer (score 0):

You need add permission "publish_actions" in your app goto settings permissions > User & Friend Permissions > "publish_actions"